# WebStorm failing to start with 'idea.system.path' error

Tags: linux, ide, webstorm

I was saving a file earlier and webstorm started throwing errors as I was saving saying the an 'idea' file was read only. It was unresponsive so I killed the process. Aftr I tried to restart WebStorm and I got the following error:

Temp directory '/home/xxxxxx/.WebStorm8/system/tmp' is inaccessible.
If you have modified the 'idea.system.path' property please make sure it is correct,
otherwise please re-install the IDE.

I am using Linux operating system. LXDE to be specific. Also I have not tried to re install the IDE as that will be my last resort. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have decided to just try an uninstall but it wont let me remove webstorm. I run rm -rf ~/.WebStorm8 and it says cannot remove and that the files are read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this was Linux trying to protect the file system from becoming corrupted. When Linux thinks that a file can become corrupted it switches the files to read only to avoid corruption. A simple restart fixed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me the cause was my laptop simply **ran out of free disk space**. After a clean-up WebStorm started flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by running it as root once from command line.
for me it was

```
cd /usr/bin/webstorm/bin
sudo ./webstorm.sh
```